# Why did Doomsday fall back to earth but Superman didn't?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

Doomsday did not have flight ability until after he fell to earth and went through further metamorphosis, so until then he had no means of propelling himself back to Earth (he could have the flight power inducing metamorphosis while floating in the space but that is not what we see in the movie).

Ideally, the shockwave from the nuclear explosion should have pushed them both further up into the space. But if we assume there was no air so high up there to create the shockwave, then either both of them should've fallen back to earth or both should've kept floating in space. There doesn't seem to be a reason for one of them to fall back while the other did not.

So why did Doomsday fall back to earth after the nuclear blast but Superman didn't?

Comment: 1. Maybe because Supes can fly, and Dooms can't, at that point. So naturally, Dooms was pulled back by Gravity.

Comment: 2. Because, plot. :)

Comment: Why does a coin turn up heads or tails?

Comment: @sanpaco - Yes, but in a coin toss there is 50/50 probability of both outcomes. In this case, there is much much higher probability of both of them either staying up or both of them falling to Earth. There's simply no net downward force (just gravity in this case) on Doomsday that Superman was also not subjected to. Further, since the nuclear blast came from below (the missile flying up from the Earth), they should both be pushed further up in the space anyway.

Comment: Yet by acknowledging that there is any chance at all that they both could stay in space you have to accept that there is a chance one could fall to earth while the other doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A blast directly between them would propel them in opposite directions, and they could be propelled at other angles depending on the blast center.

The real reason is likely not scientific at all, but written that way to serve a purpose.  Superman is healed by our sun.  It was dark where the battle was.  Floating in space was the ideal place to have him healed.  The more sunlight he gets, the faster he heals.  If Doomsday doesn't fall, he's stuck up there.  It would seem natural for the path of events to unfold this way for the battle to continue.  Otherwise Superman could just fly Doomsday right into the sun and it would be over, which is probably why they were in space to begin with.